# Possibility to use orderby="random", limit="10" and paginate="bottom" together?

Tags: pagination, entries, orderby

I tried somthing like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="images" limit="10" orderby="random" paginate="bottom"}
{title}<br>
{paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

but it doesn't work!

Every time i switch to previous page i got random images.
I there any add-ons that can do this?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: You need to explain better what it is you're trying to do. You've got orderby="random" in your channel entries tag but it sounds like you're not expecting entries to be random from your last comment so it's unclear what's intended.

Comment: I know what they mean... if you have say 200 entries, but want to limit them to 10 per page, but on the first page load it is randomised. So the 200 are pulled at random, the first 10 are shown, when navigating by pagination, it remembers the random order pulled so you dont they are not randomly generated again for every page load. I can only think this is possible in Javascript, unless EE pulls ALL entries and remembers them somewhere, but then that may be slow for large databases. Its a big flaw in my opinion, as we need random entries, but we have pagination.